# For loop versus while and next performance

Tags: python, performance, iteration, python-internals

In some cases of looping through a generator, it seems more natural to use `while` and `next` (with a `try/except StopIteration`) than the simpler for loop. Yet this comes a significant performance cost.

What is happening here, and what is the right way to approach the choice?

See example code and timing below:

```py
%%timeit
for x in gen():
    pass
# 180 µs ± 8.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
_gen = gen()
try:
    while True:
        x = next(_gen)
except StopIteration:
    pass
# 606 µs ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


# Alternative use of next: But I don't see any good reason to use it.
%%timeit
_gen = gen()
while True:
    try:
        x = next(_gen)
    except StopIteration:
        break
# 676 µs ± 24.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: If I may ask, in which cases would you consider options 2 or 3 more natural?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: The lookup of the global name `next` is one of the reasons that makes the while loop slower. `for x in gen(): next` is 4 times slower than `for x in gen(): pass` on my machine.

Comment: `try: ... except: ...` are expensive in python, and less so but there's an expression evaluated on each iteration, that in this case is just `True` but evaluated nevertheless, those µs add up

Comment: @barmar, it's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time you should use the `for` loop. It does a few things for you, that may be tedious to do yourself:

- Works for iterables and iterators.
- Handles `StopIteration` for you (in CPython the `StopIteration` is handled in C instead of Python, making it significantly faster)

That means you have more general code and faster code with `for`. So it should always be the preferred option.

However in some cases you cannot use a `for` loop, then a `while` loop is a good choice. To make it more general you should also use `iter` on the argument, so you can also process iterables which are not iterators:

```py
_gen = iter(gen())
...
```

The next question you need to ask yourself is: Do you need to handle `StopIteration` for each `next` call or is it irrelevant where the `StopIteration` happens?

Entering/Leaving the `try` doesn't have much overhead (that just applies to the `try` - if it has to go into the `except`, `else` or `finally` there's significant more overhead) but it's still overhead. That's why your second example is faster than the third. So if it doesn't matter where the `StopIteration` comes from then wrapping the `while True` in a `try` will be the faster option:

```
try:
    while True:
        next(_gen)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

There are a few options to make the `while` approach faster. One would be to avoid the global name lookup for `next` that happens once for each iteration.

By using a local variable this lookup cost happens only once and the local name lookup inside the loop is a bit faster:

```py
def f(gen):
    _gen = iter(gen())
    _next = next
    try:
        while True:
            x = _next(_gen)
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

That would be my favorite approach if I had to use the `while` loop approach.

You could even go a step further and avoid the `__next__` lookup that happens every time you call `next`. However that's something that will (in some circumstances) deviate from the pure `next` behavior and should only be done **if you know what you're doing** and only if you **really need the very small performance boost** this gives you. In general you **should NOT use that**:

```py
def f(gen):
    _gen = iter(gen())
    _next = _gen.__next__
    try:
        while True:
            x = _next()
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

However I don't recommend that approach. And one shouldn't really call double-underscore functions directly. I just mention it for completeness.

---

I also did a benchmark to display the performance of these approaches:

[image]

```py
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder

b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def for_loop(gen):
    for i in gen:
        pass

@b.add_function()
def while_outer_try(gen):
    _gen = iter(gen)
    try:
        while True:
            x = next(_gen)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

@b.add_function()       
def while_inner_try(gen):
    _gen = iter(gen)
    while True:
        try:
            x = next(_gen)
        except StopIteration:
            break

@b.add_function()
def while_outer_try_cache_next(gen):
    _gen = iter(gen)
    _next = next
    try:
        while True:
            x = _next(_gen)
    except StopIteration:
        return

@b.add_function() 
def while_outer_try_cache_next_method(gen):
    _gen = iter(gen)
    _next = _gen.__next__
    try:
        while True:
            x = _next()
    except StopIteration:
        return

@b.add_arguments('length')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 20):
        size = 2**exp
        yield size, range(size)

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

---

Summary:

- Use the `for` loop approach whenever possible and feasible.
- When you use a `while` approach make sure you use `iter` on the iterable. If you want to squeeze out some better performance: put the `try` and `except` outside the `while` (if possible) and cache the `next` lookup (don't cache the `__next__` lookup, except you really know what you will bring onto yourself and you need to squeeze out even more performance).
- A `while` approach will always be slower than `for` (at least in CPython) and require significantly more code. To repeat myself: Only use it if really necessary.

Comment: Beautifully complete answer, and +1 for pointing to `BenchmarkBuilder`. Thanks.